# AutoIncrement Column HTML doesnt show after sending Mail

Tags: c#, html, css, email

I have to send a Table that have a column with autoincrement number and when I sent the mail it shows the second column values but none the auto increment numbers:
This is my html script generated by c# code:

```html
<style>
    .tableOrder {
        counter-reset: rowNumber;
        border-collapse: collapse;
        text-align: center;
    }

    .tableOrder tr .counterColumn {
        counter-increment: rowNumber;
    }

    .tableOrder tr .counterColumn:first-child::before {
        content: counter(rowNumber);
        min-width: 1em;
        margin-right: 0.5em;
    }
</style>

</table>
<font> This is the following order of Pickups Arrives </font> <br><br>
<table class="tableOrder" border="1">
    <tr style="background-color:#6FA1D2;color:#ffffff;">
        <td style="color:#555555;">Order Arrive</td>
        <td style="color:#555555;">Pickup Number</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td class="counterColumn"></td>
        <td>1</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td class="counterColumn"></td>
        <td>1233</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td class="counterColumn"></td>
        <td>521346</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td class="counterColumn"></td>
        <td>1246</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td class="counterColumn"></td>
        <td>7594</td>
    </tr>
</table>
```

and when  I run my code and sent the email it didn't show the autoincrement values column
I'm using the SmtpClient in C#

```
MailMessage message = new MailMessage()
{
    From = fromEmail,
    Subject = "Subject",
    IsBodyHtml = true,
    Body = htmlString,
};
message.To.Add(toEmail);
message.CC.Add(ccEmail);
```

Comment: It's possible that the email reader does not support the CSS `counter-*` stylings - see https://www.campaignmonitor.com/css/

Comment: I think its the only explanation:(